# ffmpeg generate and use different palette for every frame

Tags: ffmpeg, gif

Following [this tutorial](http://blog.pkh.me/p/21-high-quality-gif-with-ffmpeg.html) I managed to create high quality gifs in reasonable memory size.

Using piping, what I'm currently doing is this

```
# Generate palette
ffmpeg -y -i - -vf fps=15,scale=600:-1:flags=lanczos,palettegen some_dir/palette.png

# Generate gif using palette
ffmpeg -y -i - -i some_dir/palette.png -filter_complex fps=15,scale=600:-1:flags=lanczos[x];[x][1:v]paletteuse output.gif
```

This is working great, but I read in the tutorial above that it is possible to generate a different palette for EVERY frame, how can I do that ? (Generate and use different palette for every frame)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is possible. Tutorial is outdated.

`ffmpeg.exe -i Wildlife.wmv -lavfi palettegen=stats_mode=single[pal],[0:v][pal]paletteuse=new=1 out.mp4`

Comment: Did you mean out.gif? Because running this command with `out.gif` resulted me in the following error `Error initializing filter 'palettegen' with args 'stats_mode=single'
Error initializing complex filters.
Invalid argument`

Comment: Your ffmpeg is prahistoric.

Comment: `ffmpeg version 2.8.11` not good enough?

Comment: This actually works in ffmpeg 3.3.3 - accepted.
How would you run it on a series of pictures instead of a video?

Comment: By using image2 muxer? `ffmpeg.exe -i Wildlife.wmv -lavfi palettegen=stats_mode=single[pal],[0:v][pal]paletteuse=new=1 out%04d.png` ?

Comment: @PaulB.Mahol thanx for the solution! Is it possible to generate 1 palette per, let's say, 30 frames? Because it seems like the performance is terrible when generating palette for each frame.

Comment: Currently not in code.

Comment: on ubuntu 16 lts the version in apt is `2.8.15`