# How do I use palettegen and paletteuse on the same command with FFmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, animated-gif

I'm trying to use `FFmpeg` to convert a bunch of Png's into a gif, while setting the duration of each frame and while using an optimal palette (and other parameters, such as `dither`) on a single command.

I was reading [FFmpeg's page](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#palettegen-1), but the examples are using two commands and a temporary `palette.png` file.

---

Here's what I got, without using `palettegen` and `paletteuse`:

```
-vsync 2 -safe 0 -f concat -i "concat.txt" -y "example.gif"
```

The `concat.txt` file contains each frame path and duration, like:

```
file 'C:\0.png'  
duration 0.066
```

It outputs a gif with a default palette as expected.

---

So, my question is how can I use `palettegen` and `paletteuse` on the same command, without a temporary file?

Comment: Oh c'mon. How is this question a duplicate of the other two questions?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, It's working now with this command from another [SuperUser answer](https://superuser.com/a/1239082/597992):

```
-vsync 2 -safe 0 -f concat -i "concat.txt" 
-lavfi palettegen=stats_mode=single[pal],[0:v][pal]paletteuse=new=1 -y "example.gif"
```